# Error: ClassCastException occured while adding dependency jar in pom.xml

Tags: maven

Can any one suggest how to resolve the `ClassCastException` while adding dependency jar in `pom.xml`?

I have created a new maven project having returning the object in runtime and then execute the ovverride method definition as based upon client request.

Ex:  actionPerform(actionType) -- this method return the 'Object'

```java
public static CommonActions action(ActionTypes actionType) 
{
    return (CommonActions)actionPerform(actionType);
}
```

1. Code is working fine and then successfully executing. There is no `ClassCastException`s **while adding this jar into library tab on project properties using eclipse**.
2. Getting `ClassCastException`s on above return statement while adding the below depenedency in pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amadeus.selenium.merci</groupId>
    <artifactId>appium-amadeus-utilities</artifactId>
    <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am using maven version 3.0.4

Please suggest how I resolve the `ClassCastException` at runtime while adding dependency jar in `pom.xml`.

Comment: Can you update your question with your `pom.xml`? Probably is an inherited dependency causing this issue.

Comment: I just added **simple dependeny attributes values ** which is in above. Currently I am unable to edit my question.  For more details, I will send you the mail. Please share your email address.